# ng-class syntax in symfony2 project

Tags: angularjs, symfony, ng-class

I'm using AngularJS in my front end of my web application which is in Symfony2 so i changed the separator of angular from {{ }} to [[ ]] by

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
```

Every thing seems to work fine with `ng-hide="" and  ng-repeat=""`  etc.. 
But i need to use ng-class which is normally uses this syntax :

```
ng-class="{redstyle: true  }"
```

but it is not working, any one knows how should it be in my case ?

Comment: Why is it that you are changing the interpolator? If it's so that you can use them in the a twig template without breaking it you can always use `{% verbatim %}{% endverbatim %}` to print text rather than parsing it.

Comment: because all the front end part is with angular.js so i'm using objects and attributes from my angular controllers for example  [[myAngularObject.Name]] or [[ MyangularObject.index]] so i was obliged to change the interpolator of angular

Comment: yes @Qoop to avoid conflicts problems

Comment: Are you mixing html and javascript in the same templates, or using parameters passed in from your controllers in the javascript?

Comment: No Qoop my templates contains only Html/twig, the javascript is the other files ofcourse

Comment: Sorry, it may be blindingly obvious but I'm just not seeing it. How come you needed to change the interpolation symbols to just use them in javascript files?

Comment: it is not a small application (so i can't post all my javascript code), i got an mvc architecture in my front end side and the interpolation change is made in my main.js file and it is working,i got only a problem with ng-class